# Error when rendering Nav.Link in react-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I pasted this example code directly from react-bootstraps official page and I can't get it to work. The strange thing is that it all works fine as soon as I remove the Nav.Link lines in the code. Why can't I render Nav.Link?

Here's my code (App.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Nav';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Form';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/lib/FormControl';
```

The Api says that i should use

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
```

instead of

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
```

but when I do that, it doesn't find the files at all and gives me the error

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js 
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/Button' in '/Users/xxx/repos/admin-ui/application/src'
```

Render function (taken directly from [this react-bootstrap example](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/navbar/))

```
return (
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
          <Form inline>
            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
            <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
          </Form>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
```

This is the error that I get. Lines 47 and 48 that the error triggers on are the Nav.Link lines.

[image: The error]

Comment: Would you be able to post the version of react-bootstrap that you have added to your project? You can get that with `npm show react-bootstrap`.

Comment: react-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5

Comment: Hmm... that is strange. From everything you've described (you can see my answer below), it would seem that you are using version `0.32.4` or earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's hard to know for sure without seeing your code and your setup, my *guess* is that you are using a version of `react-bootstrap` that is earlier than `1.0.0` - **perhaps you are using `0.32.4` or earlier?** This is my guess because:

- `Nav.Link` wasn't introduced into the package until `1.0.0` and later
- Prior to `1.0.0`, the way to import components was to import from the `lib` sub-folder (for example: `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button`). From `1.0.0` and on, you would import according to their current documentation: `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button`.

So, my guess is that **you are using an old version of `react-bootstrap`**.

At lines 47 and 48, you are trying to access `<Nav.Link>`, but there is no such thing (in the version of the package you are using). You can change your `render` code to use `<Nav.Nysithea>` (for example) and you would get the exact same error message.

---

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/43vnm4j31w) that I created that uses your code and replicates the same error that you're seeing in the `<Nav.Link>` lines. If you remove the lines, then the page loads.

In that code sandbox, I have added the `react-bootstrap` dependency with version `0.32.4`. If you were to change that dependency version to the latest version (currently, that's `1.0.0-beta.5`) and remove the `/lib` sub-folder from all of the `import` statements, then the page loads and the `<Nav.Link>` is accessible.

---

To confirm that you are using a version of `react-bootstrap` prior to the introduction of `Nav.Link`, you can do this at your command line:

```
npm show react-bootstrap
# OR
yarn list react-bootstrap
```

What version of the package are you using?

If it's before `1.0.0`, and you *want* to use `Nav.Link`, then I would recommend doing the following:

1. Edit your `package.json` file to make sure you use a more recent version of the package. Look for the line that includes `react-bootstrap`. Edit the line to look like the following:

```
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0"
```

This will ensure that you are running `react-bootstrap` version `1.*`

2. Delete your `node_modules` folder.
3. Run `npm install`

After all of your packages install, you can check your `react-bootstrap` version again (see above) to verify that it is at least `1.0.0`. If so, then you should have access to `Nav.Link`.

Comment: Somehow, npm show react-bootstrap says that I have 1.0.0-beta.5, but when I checked my package.json file, the version was 0.31.5 just like you said. I don't know the reason for this, but your answer solved my problem, thanks! :)